# Converting amount to words in RDLC

Tags: c#, report, rdlc

In my `rdlc` file i just want to convert a `decimal number in  words` .

Like '`125.2' as 'One hundred and twenty five point two five'`. I searched in  Google and used some code but i couldn't convert the decimal point. If any body knows please share.

Answer (score 7):

write the following code in RDlc Code .Select and open the Rdlc Report -> Right Click-> select the code tag or find menu Report and select "Report Property" than select "Code" Tab
and write the following

```
Function RupeesToWord(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Temp
Dim Rupees, Paisa As String
Dim DecimalPlace, iCount
Dim Hundreds, Words As String
Dim place(9) As String
place(0) = " Thousand "
place(2) = " Lakh "
place(4) = " Crore "
place(6) = " Arab "
place(8) = " Kharab "
On Error Resume Next
' Convert MyNumber to a string, trimming extra spaces.
MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))

' Find decimal place.
DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")

' If we find decimal place...
If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
' Convert Paisa
Temp = Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2)
Paisa = " and " & ConvertTens(Temp) & " Paisa"
Paisa = ""

' Strip off paisa from remainder to convert.
MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
End If

'===============================================================
Dim TM As String ' If MyNumber between Rs.1 To 99 Only.
TM = Right(MyNumber, 2)

If Len(MyNumber) > 0 And Len(MyNumber) <= 2 Then
If Len(TM) = 1 Then
Words = ConvertDigit(TM)
RupeesToWord = "Rupees " & Words & Paisa & " Only"

Exit Function

Else
If Len(TM) = 2 Then
Words = ConvertTens(TM)
RupeesToWord = "Rupees " & Words & Paisa & " Only"
Exit Function

End If
End If
End If
'===============================================================


' Convert last 3 digits of MyNumber to ruppees in word.
Hundreds = ConvertHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
' Strip off last three digits
MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)

iCount = 0
Do While MyNumber <> ""
'Strip last two digits
Temp = Right(MyNumber, 2)
If Len(MyNumber) = 1 Then


If Trim(Words) = "Thousand" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Lakh Thousand" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Lakh" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Crore" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Crore Lakh Thousand" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Arab Crore Lakh Thousand" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Arab" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Kharab Arab Crore Lakh Thousand" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Kharab" Then

Words = ConvertDigit(Temp) & place(iCount)
MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 1)

Else

Words = ConvertDigit(Temp) & place(iCount) & Words
MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 1)

End If
Else

If Trim(Words) = "Thousand" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Lakh Thousand" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Lakh" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Crore" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Crore Lakh Thousand" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Arab Crore Lakh Thousand" Or _
Trim(Words) = "Arab" Then


Words = ConvertTens(Temp) & place(iCount)


MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 2)
Else

'=================================================================
' if only Lakh, Crore, Arab, Kharab

If Trim(ConvertTens(Temp) & place(iCount)) = "Lakh" Or _
Trim(ConvertTens(Temp) & place(iCount)) = "Crore" Or _
Trim(ConvertTens(Temp) & place(iCount)) = "Arab" Then

Words = Words
MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 2)
Else
Words = ConvertTens(Temp) & place(iCount) & Words
MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 2)
End If

End If
End If

iCount = iCount + 2
Loop

RupeesToWord = "Rupees " & Words & Hundreds & Paisa & " Only"
End Function

' Conversion for hundreds
'*****************************************
Private Function ConvertHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
Dim Result As String

' Exit if there is nothing to convert.
If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function

' Append leading zeros to number.
MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)

' Do we have a hundreds place digit to convert?
If Left(MyNumber, 1) <> "0" Then
Result = ConvertDigit(Left(MyNumber, 1)) & " Hundreds "
End If

' Do we have a tens place digit to convert?
If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
Result = Result & ConvertTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
Else
' If not, then convert the ones place digit.
Result = Result & ConvertDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
End If

ConvertHundreds = Trim(Result)
End Function

' Conversion for tens
'*****************************************
Private Function ConvertTens(ByVal MyTens)
Dim Result As String

' Is value between 10 and 19?
If Val(Left(MyTens, 1)) = 1 Then
Select Case Val(MyTens)
Case 10 : Result = "Ten"
Case 11 : Result = "Eleven"
Case 12 : Result = "Twelve"
Case 13 : Result = "Thirteen"
Case 14 : Result = "Fourteen"
Case 15 : Result = "Fifteen"
Case 16 : Result = "Sixteen"
Case 17 : Result = "Seventeen"
Case 18 : Result = "Eighteen"
Case 19 : Result = "Nineteen"
Case Else
End Select
Else
' .. otherwise it's between 20 and 99.
Select Case Val(Left(MyTens, 1))
Case 2 : Result = "Twenty "
Case 3 : Result = "Thirty "
Case 4 : Result = "Forty "
Case 5 : Result = "Fifty "
Case 6 : Result = "Sixty "
Case 7 : Result = "Seventy "
Case 8 : Result = "Eighty "
Case 9 : Result = "Ninety "
Case Else
End Select

' Convert ones place digit.
Result = Result & ConvertDigit(Right(MyTens, 1))
End If

ConvertTens = Result
End Function

Private Function ConvertDigit(ByVal MyDigit)
Select Case Val(MyDigit)
Case 1 : ConvertDigit = "One"
Case 2 : ConvertDigit = "Two"
Case 3 : ConvertDigit = "Three"
Case 4 : ConvertDigit = "Four"
Case 5 : ConvertDigit = "Five"
Case 6 : ConvertDigit = "Six"
Case 7 : ConvertDigit = "Seven"
Case 8 : ConvertDigit = "Eight"
Case 9 : ConvertDigit = "Nine"
Case Else : ConvertDigit = ""
End Select
End Function
```

and

Select the expression of your total price field , add Like that

```
=Code.RupeesToWord( Fields!deci_NetAmt.Value)
```

Or if you need in footer of page add like this

```
=Code.RupeesToWord(Sum(ReportItems!deci_NetAmt.Value))
```

Fixed the error from the code snippet. Now it can be used without fixing any error suggested by other members.

Comment: RupeesToWord is giving error while trying to get on the expression.

Comment: Removed - ' -  from the starting of  line  -- 'Paisa = " and " & ConvertTens(Temp) & " Paisa"--Now works fine

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in above code.

```
Temp = Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2)
'Paisa = " and " & ConvertTens(Temp) & " Paisa"
Paisa = ""
```

In the above code you need to remove ' before Paisa like:

```
Temp = Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2)
Paisa = " and " & ConvertTens(Temp) & " Paisa"
Paisa = ""
```

Now this will help you working fine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in above code.

```
Temp = Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2)
'Paisa = " and " & ConvertTens(Temp) & " Paisa"
Paisa = ""
```

In the above code you need to remove and replace Blow Code

```
Temp = Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2)
if Temp >0 then
Paisa = " and " & ConvertTens(Temp) & " Paisa"
end if
```

Comment: yes, you really found the error. Thanks, Now its running