# Convert Number to Word in rdlc report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, rdlc

In rdlc report I faced some problem for converting number to word. Like 415,070.00 it should be showed (Four Hundred Fifteen Thousand Seventy),
But it show  (Four Hundred Fifteen Thousand and Hundred Seventy). 
But another rdlc file in my project for same value it work fine. but some rdlc file i getting this error. in below i give the code which i used in Report properties code menu option.

"415069 expect the output (Four hundred fifteen thousand sixty nine) but actual output is Four hundred fifteen thousand and hundred sixty nine."

```vb
Dim GroupCounter as Integer=0
Dim GroupCounter1 as Integer=0
Dim GroupCounter2 as Integer=0
Dim GroupCounter3 as Integer=0
Function GetGroupCounter() as String
    GroupCounter=GroupCounter+1
    return GroupCounter.ToString()
End Function

Function GetGroupCounter1() as String
    GroupCounter1=GroupCounter1+1
    return GroupCounter1.ToString()
End Function

Function GetGroupCounter2() as String
    GroupCounter2=GroupCounter2+1
    return GroupCounter2.ToString()
End Function

Function GetGroupCounter3() as String
    GroupCounter3=GroupCounter3+1
    return GroupCounter3.ToString()
End Function
Public Shared Function changeToWords(ByVal numb As [String]) As [String]
    Dim val As [String] = "", wholeNo As [String] = numb, points As [String] = "", andStr As [String] = "", pointStr As [String] = ""
    Dim endStr As [String] = ""
    Try
        Dim decimalPlace As Integer = numb.IndexOf(".")
        If decimalPlace > 0 Then
            wholeNo = numb.Substring(0, decimalPlace)
            points = numb.Substring(decimalPlace + 1)
            If Convert.ToInt32(points) > 0 Then
                andStr = "point"
                ' just to separate whole numbers from points
                pointStr = translateCents(points)
            End If
        End If
        val = [String].Format("{0} {1}{2} {3}", translateWholeNumber(wholeNo).Trim(), andStr, pointStr, endStr)
    Catch


    End Try
    Return val
End Function
Private Shared Function translateWholeNumber(ByVal number As [String]) As [String]
    Dim word As String = ""
    Try
        Dim beginsZero As Boolean = False
        'tests for 0XX
        Dim isDone As Boolean = False
        'test if already translated
        Dim dblAmt As Double = (Convert.ToDouble(number))
        'if ((dblAmt > 0) && number.StartsWith("0"))
        If dblAmt > 0 Then
            'test for zero or digit zero in a nuemric
            beginsZero = number.StartsWith("0")

            Dim numDigits As Integer = number.Length
            Dim pos As Integer = 0
            'store digit grouping
            Dim place As [String] = ""
            'digit grouping name:hundres,thousand,etc...
            Select Case numDigits
                Case 1
                    'ones' range
                    word = ones(number)
                    isDone = True
                    Exit Select
                Case 2
                    'tens' range
                    word = tens(number)
                    isDone = True
                    Exit Select
                Case 3
                    'hundreds' range
                    pos = (numDigits Mod 3) + 1
                    place = " Hundred "
                    Exit Select
                'thousands' range
                Case 4, 5, 6
                    pos = (numDigits Mod 4) + 1
                    place = " Thousand "
                    Exit Select
                'millions' range
                Case 7, 8, 9
                    pos = (numDigits Mod 7) + 1
                    place = " Million "
                    Exit Select
                Case 10
                    'Billions's range
                    pos = (numDigits Mod 10) + 1
                    place = " Billion "
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    'add extra case options for anything above Billion...
                    isDone = True
                    Exit Select
            End Select
            If Not isDone Then
                'if transalation is not done, continue...(Recursion comes in now!!)
                word = translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(0, pos)) + place + translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(pos))
                'check for trailing zeros
                If beginsZero Then
                    word = " and " & word.Trim()
                End If
            End If
            'ignore digit grouping names
            If word.Trim().Equals(place.Trim()) Then
                word = ""
            End If
        End If
    Catch


    End Try
    Return word.Trim()
End Function
Private Shared Function tens(ByVal digit As [String]) As [String]
    Dim digt As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(digit)
    Dim name As [String] = Nothing
    Select Case digt
        Case 10
            name = "Ten"
            Exit Select
        Case 11
            name = "Eleven"
            Exit Select
        Case 12
            name = "Twelve"
            Exit Select
        Case 13
            name = "Thirteen"
            Exit Select
        Case 14
            name = "Fourteen"
            Exit Select
        Case 15
            name = "Fifteen"
            Exit Select
        Case 16
            name = "Sixteen"
            Exit Select
        Case 17
            name = "Seventeen"
            Exit Select
        Case 18
            name = "Eighteen"
            Exit Select
        Case 19
            name = "Nineteen"
            Exit Select
        Case 20
            name = "Twenty"
            Exit Select
        Case 30
            name = "Thirty"
            Exit Select
        Case 40
            name = "Forty"
            Exit Select
        Case 50
            name = "Fifty"
            Exit Select
        Case 60
            name = "Sixty"
            Exit Select
        Case 70
            name = "Seventy"
            Exit Select
        Case 80
            name = "Eighty"
            Exit Select
        Case 90
            name = "Ninety"
            Exit Select
        Case Else
            If digt > 0 Then
                name = (tens(digit.Substring(0, 1) & "0") & " ") + ones(digit.Substring(1))
            End If
            Exit Select
    End Select
    Return name
End Function
Private Shared Function ones(ByVal digit As [String]) As [String]
    Dim digt As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(digit)
    Dim name As [String] = ""
    Select Case digt
        Case 1
            name = "One"
            Exit Select
        Case 2
            name = "Two"
            Exit Select
        Case 3
            name = "Three"
            Exit Select
        Case 4
            name = "Four"
            Exit Select
        Case 5
            name = "Five"
            Exit Select
        Case 6
            name = "Six"
            Exit Select
        Case 7
            name = "Seven"
            Exit Select
        Case 8
            name = "Eight"
            Exit Select
        Case 9
            name = "Nine"
            Exit Select
    End Select
    Return name
End Function
Private Shared Function translateCents(ByVal cents As [String]) As [String]
    Dim cts As [String] = "", digit As [String] = "", engOne As [String] = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To cents.Length - 1
        digit = cents(i).ToString()
        If digit.Equals("0") Then
            engOne = "Zero"
        Else
            engOne = ones(digit)
        End If
        cts += " " & engOne
    Next
    Return cts
End Function
```

Comment: Had a quick look at this and the problem is on the line `word = translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(0, pos)) + place + translateWholeNumber(number.Substring(pos))` - `number.Substring(0, pos)` is zero. Haven't got time to work out a fix, sorry.

Comment: Exit Select is not necessary in vb.net.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt. Not tested exhaustively. If used an enum to get the words. I believe it is a bit shorter than your code.

```
Private Enum NumWords
    None = 0
    One = 1
    Two = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
    Five = 5
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Eleven = 11
    Twelve = 12
    Thirteen = 13
    Fourteen = 14
    Fifteen = 15
    Sixteen = 16
    Seventeen = 17
    Eighteen = 18
    Nineteen = 19
    Twenty = 20
    Thirty = 30
    Forty = 40
    Fifty = 50
    Sixty = 60
    Seventy = 70
    Eignty = 80
    Ninety = 90
End Enum

Private Function ConvertNumbersToString(input As String) As String
    Dim s As String = ""
    'split out pennies
    Dim numString = input.Split("."c)
    If numString.Length = 1 Then
        'We only have pennies
        Return $"No Dollars and {EvaluateGroup(numString(0))} Cents"
    End If
    'Divide string into groups of 3 or less
    Dim groups = numString(0).Split(","c).ToList
    Do
        s &= EvaluateGroup(groups(0))
        Select Case groups.Count
            Case 1
                Exit Do
            Case 2
                If groups(0) <> "000" Then
                    s &= "Thousand "
                End If
            Case 3
                If groups(0) <> "000" Then
                    s &= "Million "
                End If
            Case 4
                s &= "Billion "
            Case Else
                Return " Too Big!"
        End Select
        groups.RemoveAt(0)
    Loop
    s &= "Dollars "
    If numString(1) = "00" Then
        s &= "and no cents"
        Return s
    Else
        Dim cents As String = $" and {EvaluateGroup(numString(1))}"
        s &= cents
        If numString(1) = "01" Then
            s &= " cent"
        Else
            s &= " cents"
        End If
    End If
    Return s
End Function

Private Function EvaluateGroup(input As String) As String
    Dim s As String = ""
    Select Case input.Length
        Case 1
            If input(0) <> "0" Then
                Return DirectCast(CInt(input), NumWords).ToString & " "
            Else
                Return s
            End If
        Case 2
            'We have a teen
            If input(0) = "1" Then
                Return DirectCast(CInt(input), NumWords).ToString & " "
            End If
            If input(0) <> "0" Then
                s &= DirectCast(CInt(input(0).ToString & "0"), NumWords).ToString & " "
                If input(1) <> "0" Then
                    s &= (DirectCast(CInt(input(1).ToString), NumWords)).ToString & " "
                End If
                Return s
            ElseIf input(1) <> "0" Then
                s &= DirectCast(CInt(input(1).ToString), NumWords).ToString & " "
            End If
        Case 3
            If input(0) <> "0"c Then
                s = DirectCast(CInt(input(0).ToString), NumWords).ToString & " Hundred "
                If input(1) <> "0" Then
                    If input(1) <> "1" Then
                        s &= DirectCast(CInt(input(1).ToString & "0"), NumWords).ToString & " "
                    Else
                        s &= DirectCast(CInt(input(1).ToString & input(2).ToString), NumWords).ToString
                        Return s
                    End If
                End If
                If input(2) <> "0" Then
                    s &= DirectCast(CInt(input(2).ToString), NumWords).ToString & " "
                End If
                Return s
            Else
                If input(1) <> "0" Then
                    s = DirectCast(CInt(input(1).ToString & "0"), NumWords).ToString & " "
                    If input(2) <> "0" Then
                        s &= DirectCast(CInt(input(2).ToString), NumWords).ToString & " "
                    End If
                Else
                    s = DirectCast(CInt(input(2).ToString), NumWords).ToString
                End If
            End If
    End Select
    Return s
End Function
```

To use the functions...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim d As Decimal
    'Make sure you have valid input
    If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, d) Then
        'Make sure the format is compatible with the code
        TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0,12:N2}", d).Trim
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number.")
        Return
    End If
    TextBox2.Text = ConvertNumbersToString(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

click-> Report from menu then select "Report Property" than select "Code" Tab and write the code as its

```
function RupeesToWord(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Temp
    Dim Rupees, Paisa As String
    Dim DecimalPlace, iCount
    Dim Hundreds, Words As String
    Dim place(9) As String
    place(0) = " Thousand "
    place(2) = " Lakh "
    place(4) = " Crore "
    place(6) = " Arab "
    place(8) = " Kharab "
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Convert MyNumber to a string, trimming extra spaces.
    MyNumber = Trim(Str(MyNumber))
    
    ' Find decimal place.
    DecimalPlace = InStr(MyNumber, ".")
    
    ' If we find decimal place...
    If DecimalPlace > 0 Then
    ' Convert Paisa
    Temp = Left(Mid(MyNumber, DecimalPlace + 1) & "00", 2)
    if Temp >0 then
    Paisa = " and " & ConvertTens(Temp) & " Paisa"
    end if
    
    ' Strip off paisa from remainder to convert.
    MyNumber = Trim(Left(MyNumber, DecimalPlace - 1))
    End If
    
    '===============================================================
    Dim TM As String ' If MyNumber between Rs.1 To 99 Only.
    TM = Right(MyNumber, 2)
    
    If Len(MyNumber) > 0 And Len(MyNumber) <= 2 Then
    If Len(TM) = 1 Then
    Words = ConvertDigit(TM)
    RupeesToWord = "(" & Words & Paisa & " Only)"
    
    Exit Function
    
    Else
    If Len(TM) = 2 Then
    Words = ConvertTens(TM)
    RupeesToWord = "(" & Words & Paisa & " Only)"
    Exit Function
    
    End If
    End If
    End If
    '===============================================================
    
    
    ' Convert last 3 digits of MyNumber to ruppees in word.
    Hundreds = ConvertHundreds(Right(MyNumber, 3))
    ' Strip off last three digits
    MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 3)
    
    iCount = 0
    Do While MyNumber <> ""
    'Strip last two digits
    Temp = Right(MyNumber, 2)
    If Len(MyNumber) = 1 Then
    
    
    If Trim(Words) = "Thousand" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Lakh Thousand" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Lakh" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Crore" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Crore Lakh Thousand" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Arab Crore Lakh Thousand" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Arab" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Kharab Arab Crore Lakh Thousand" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Kharab" Then
    
    Words = ConvertDigit(Temp) & place(iCount)
    MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 1)
    
    Else
    
    Words = ConvertDigit(Temp) & place(iCount) & Words
    MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 1)
    
    End If
    Else
    
    If Trim(Words) = "Thousand" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Lakh Thousand" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Lakh" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Crore" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Crore Lakh Thousand" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Arab Crore Lakh Thousand" Or _
    Trim(Words) = "Arab" Then
    
    
    Words = ConvertTens(Temp) & place(iCount)
    
    
    MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 2)
    Else
    
    '=================================================================
    ' if only Lakh, Crore, Arab, Kharab
    
    If Trim(ConvertTens(Temp) & place(iCount)) = "Lakh" Or _
    Trim(ConvertTens(Temp) & place(iCount)) = "Crore" Or _
    Trim(ConvertTens(Temp) & place(iCount)) = "Arab" Then
    
    Words = Words
    MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 2)
    Else
    Words = ConvertTens(Temp) & place(iCount) & Words
    MyNumber = Left(MyNumber, Len(MyNumber) - 2)
    End If
    
    End If
    End If
    
    iCount = iCount + 2
    Loop
    
    RupeesToWord = "(" & Words & Paisa & " Only)"
    End Function
    
    ' Conversion for hundreds
    '*****************************************
    Private Function ConvertHundreds(ByVal MyNumber)
    Dim Result As String
    
    ' Exit if there is nothing to convert.
    If Val(MyNumber) = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    ' Append leading zeros to number.
    MyNumber = Right("000" & MyNumber, 3)
    
    ' Do we have a hundreds place digit to convert?
    If Left(MyNumber, 1) <> "0" Then
    Result = ConvertDigit(Left(MyNumber, 1)) & " Hundreds "
    End If
    
    ' Do we have a tens place digit to convert?
    If Mid(MyNumber, 2, 1) <> "0" Then
    Result = Result & ConvertTens(Mid(MyNumber, 2))
    Else
    ' If not, then convert the ones place digit.
    Result = Result & ConvertDigit(Mid(MyNumber, 3))
    End If
    
    ConvertHundreds = Trim(Result)
    End Function
    
    ' Conversion for tens
    '*****************************************
    Private Function ConvertTens(ByVal MyTens)
    Dim Result As String
    
    ' Is value between 10 and 19?
    If Val(Left(MyTens, 1)) = 1 Then
    Select Case Val(MyTens)
    Case 10 : Result = "Ten"
    Case 11 : Result = "Eleven"
    Case 12 : Result = "Twelve"
    Case 13 : Result = "Thirteen"
    Case 14 : Result = "Fourteen"
    Case 15 : Result = "Fifteen"
    Case 16 : Result = "Sixteen"
    Case 17 : Result = "Seventeen"
    Case 18 : Result = "Eighteen"
    Case 19 : Result = "Nineteen"
    Case Else
    End Select
    Else
    ' .. otherwise it's between 20 and 99.
    Select Case Val(Left(MyTens, 1))
    Case 2 : Result = "Twenty "
    Case 3 : Result = "Thirty "
    Case 4 : Result = "Forty "
    Case 5 : Result = "Fifty "
    Case 6 : Result = "Sixty "
    Case 7 : Result = "Seventy "
    Case 8 : Result = "Eighty "
    Case 9 : Result = "Ninety "
    Case Else
    End Select
    
    ' Convert ones place digit.
    Result = Result & ConvertDigit(Right(MyTens, 1))
    End If
    
    ConvertTens = Result
    End Function
    
    Private Function ConvertDigit(ByVal MyDigit)
    Select Case Val(MyDigit)
    Case 1 : ConvertDigit = "One"
    Case 2 : ConvertDigit = "Two"
    Case 3 : ConvertDigit = "Three"
    Case 4 : ConvertDigit = "Four"
    Case 5 : ConvertDigit = "Five"
    Case 6 : ConvertDigit = "Six"
    Case 7 : ConvertDigit = "Seven"
    Case 8 : ConvertDigit = "Eight"
    Case 9 : ConvertDigit = "Nine"
    Case Else : ConvertDigit = ""
    End Select
    End Function
```

then call in expression like =Code.RupeesToWord(29250.00)
ref: [reference from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354592/converting-amount-to-words-in-rdlc)